# ERROR: Extra content at the end of the document Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error

Tags: php, html, mysql

#### The exact error

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

#### My PHP file

```
 <?php
 header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
 mysql_connect( "mysql3.000webhost.com", "Username", "Password" );
 mysql_select_db( 'Ddb' );
 mysql_query( "INSERT INTO items VALUES ( null, null, '".
 mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['user'] ).
 "', '".
 mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['message'] ).
 "')" );
?>
<success/>
```

#### My HTML file (I don't think this has anything to do with the error though.)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add Definition Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="add.php" method="POST">
    User: <input name="user" /><br />
    Message: <input name="message" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### chmod 777 on all files (I know thats bad but the site isn't public yet).

#### Comment if you need more information.

Tutorial I am following http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html#l3ioschat/index.html#l3

Comment: What is the XML this is outputting? That error looks like an _XML error_, not a PHP error.

Comment: Is your server allowing outgoing connections?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski Yes it is online (and does allow outgoing) but is password protected kind of like logging into a gateway, Yes it is XML sorry

Comment: @VPRPGFerret Comment above ^

Comment: It looks like a definite problem with the XML. Try outputting as text first.

Comment: and also as a tip check your file in hex mode. you might have hidden characters at the end of the file.

Comment: I opened it as plain text in an editor that doesn't support formatting other than plain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21354/discussion-between-kuzyt-and-isaiah-turner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following exactly to the point as mentioned in the IBM document. I have uploaded a test page on http://nixblog.webatu.com/test.html and it works.

So not sure what you are doing wrong.

According to the example the database table insert is for table 'chatitems' and you seem to be using 'items'. just make sure what you are inserting is correct and that it doesnt show any database errors. to do this change 'Content-type: text/xml' to 'Content-type: text'

Comment: :) yeah its nixdevblog.com